# Set theoretical multiverse and truths

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, multiverse-of-sets

In J.D. Hamkins' [multiverse view of set theory](https://arxiv.org/abs/1108.4223), every universe has an ill-founded $\mathbb{N}$ from the perspective of another universe.  Does this mean that every proof in our universe can be seen as a nonstandard length proof from the perspective of some other universe, so that there is no real "truth" in the Multiverse?

Could this happen even for a simple concrete proof, like the fundamental theorem of arithmetic?  Or are some some proofs standard-length in all universes?

Comment: Length 35253586543 is always length 35253586543. And what proof of the fundament theorem of arithmetic uses properties of a special model of $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: The actual proofs that we use have standard lengths. The non-standard natural numbers, which account for any ill-foundedness in those systems, are larger than all the standard natural numbers. So you shouldn't expect to ever see anything of such size.

Comment: @Guest154:  You might find Viteslav Svedar's paper, "Infinite natural numbers:  an unwanted phenomenon, or a useful concept?" (look under Author and Title on the Web), of some help in understanding Hamkins' Section 5, "Multiverse Response to the Categoricity Arguments" in his paper, "The Set-Theoretic Multiverse".  Pay particular attention to the following concept found in Section 5:  "..._within any fixed set-theoretic background concept_, any set concept that has all the sets [how to define 'all'?--my comment] agrees with that background concept; and hence any two of them agree with

Comment: (cont.) each other.  But such a claim seems far from categoricity, should one entertain the idea that there can be different incompatible set-theoretic backgrounds".  (Hamkins does entertain that idea, by the way.)

Comment: Also, Victoria Gitman's boolesrings blogpost "An Introduction to Nonstandard Models of Arithmetic" (and the comments thereto) and Haim Gaifman's "Non-Standard Models in a Broader Perspective" might be helpful to you also (both are found on the Web as well).

Comment: Note also that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (since it can be derived in $PA$) holds for both standard and nonstandard integers.  A proof of this can be found in Todd Trimble's answer to Elmore's mathoverflow question, "$FTA$ in first order setting"  ($FTA$ stands for Fundamantal Theorem of Arithmetic, of course).

Comment: The fact that given any model of geometry one can build inside it various models of spherical, Euclidean and hyperbolic geometry does not imply that curvature of our own world is undefined. It may be variable, true, and unknown to us too, but locally at each point it is rigorously defined (I think).

Comment: Every [naive integer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/231111/28128) is present in the instantiation of N in each universe of the multiverse.  The point is that the naive ones don't form a set in any of them. The length of any concrete proof is certainly a naive integer.

Answer (score 29):

Thank you for your interest in my views on the set-theoretic
multiverse.

Yes, indeed, the well-foundedness mirage axiom you mention is
probably the most controversial of my multiverse axioms, and so
allow me to explain a little about it.

The axiom expresses in a strong way the idea that we don't actually
have a foundationally robust absolute concept of the finite in
mathematics. Specifically, the axiom asserts that every universe of
set theory is ill-founded even in its natural numbers from the
perspective of another, better universe. Thus, every set-theoretic
background in which we might seek to undertake our mathematical
activity is nonstandard with respect to another universe.

My intention in posing the axiom so provocatively was to point out
what I believe is the unsatisfactory nature of our philosophical
account of the finite.

You might be interested in the brief essay I wrote on the topic, [A
question for the mathematics
oracle](http://jdh.hamkins.org/question-for-the-math-oracle/),
published in the proceedings of the Singapore workshop on Infinity
and Truth. For an interesting and entertaining interlude, the
workshop organizers had requested that everyone at the workshop
pose a specific question that might be asked of an all-knowing
mathematical oracle, who would truthfully answer. My question was
whether in mathematics we really do have a absolute concept of the
finite.

To explain a bit more, the naive view of the natural numbers in
mathematics is that they are the numbers, $0$, $1$, $2$, **and so
on.** The natural numbers, with all the usual arithmetic structure,
are taken by many to have a definite absolute nature; arithmetic
truth assertions are taken to have a definite absolute nature, in
comparison for example with the comparatively less sure footing of
set-theoretic truth assertions.

To be sure, many mathematicians and philosophers have proposed a
demarcation between arithmetic and analysis, where the claims of
number theory and arithmetic are said to have a definite absolute
nature, while the assertions of higher levels of set theory,
beginning with claims about the set of sets of natural numbers, are
less definite. Nik Weaver, for example, has suggested that
classical logic is appropriate for the arithmetic realm and
intuitionistic logic for the latter realm, and a similar position
is advocated by Solomon Feferman and others.

But what exactly does this phrase, "and so on" really mean in the
naive account of the finite? It seems truly to be doing all the
work, and I find it basically inadequate to the task. The situation
is more subtle and problematic than seems to me to be typically
acknowledged. Why do people find their conception of the finite to
be so clear and absolute? It seems hopelessly vague to me.

Of course, within the axiomatic system of ZFC or other systems, we
have a clear definition of what it means to be finite. The issue is
not that, but rather the extent to which these internal accounts of
finiteness agree with the naive pre-reflective accounts of the
finite as used in the meta-theory.

Some mathematicians point to the various categoricity arguments as
an explanation of why it is meaningful to speak of the natural
numbers as a definite mathematical structure. Dedekind proved,
after all, that there is up to isomorphism only one model
$\langle\mathbb{N},S,0\rangle$ of the second-order Peano axioms,
where $0$ is not a successor, the successor function $S$ is
one-to-one, and $\mathbb{N}$ is the unique subset of $\mathbb{N}$
containing $0$ and closed under successor.

But to my way of thinking, this categoricity argument merely pushes
off the problem from arithmetic to set theory, basing the
absoluteness of arithmetic on the absoluteness of the concept of an
arbitrary set of natural numbers. But how does that give one any
confidence?

We already know very well, after all, about failures of
absoluteness in set theory. Different models of set theory can
disagree about whether the continuum hypothesis holds, whether the
axiom of choice holds, and so with innumerable examples of
non-absoluteness. Different models of set theory can disagree on
their natural number structures, and even when they agree on their
natural numbers, they can still disagree on their theories of
arithmetic truth (see [Satisfaction is not
absolute](http://jdh.hamkins.org/satisfaction-is-not-absolute/)).
So we know all about how mathematical truth assertions can seem to
be non-absolute in set theory.

Skolem pointed out that there are models of set theory $M_1$, $M_2$
and $M_3$ with a set $A$ in common, such that $M_1$ thinks $A$ is
finite; $M_2$ thinks $A$ is countably infinite and $M_3$ thinks $A$
is uncountable. For example, let $M_3$ be any countable model of
set theory, and let $M_1$ be an ultrapower by a ultrafilter on
$\mathbb{N}$ in $M_3$, and let $A$ be a nonstandard natural number
of $M_1$. So $M_1$ thinks $A$ is finite, but $M_3$ thinks $A$ has
size continuum. If $M_2$ is a forcing extension of $M_3$, we can
arrange that $A$ is countably infinite in $M_2$.

No amount of set-theoretic information in our set-theoretic
background could ever establish that our current conception of the
natural numbers, whatever it is, is the truly standard one, since
whatever we assert to be true is also true in some nonstandard
models, whose natural numbers are not standard.

The well-foundedness mirage axiom asserts that this phenomenon is
universal: all universes are wrong about well-foundedness.

In defense of the mirage axiom, let me point out that whatever attitude toward it one might harbor, nevertheless the axiom cannot be seen as incoherent or inconsistent, because Victoria Gitman and I have proved that all of my multiverse axioms are true in the multiverse consisting of the countable computably saturated models of ZFC. So the axiom is neither contradictory nor incoherent. See [A natural model of the multiverse axioms](http://jdh.hamkins.org/naturalmodelofmultiverseaxioms/).

I have discussed my multiverse views in several papers.

> > *Hamkins, Joel David*, [**The set-theoretic multiverse**](http://jdh.hamkins.org/themultiverse/), Rev. Symb. Log. 5, No. 3, 416-449 (2012). [Doi:10.1017/S1755020311000359](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S1755020311000359), [ZBL1260.03103](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1260.03103).
> >
> > *Hamkins, Joel David*, [**A multiverse perspective on the axiom of constructibility**](http://jdh.hamkins.org/multiverse-perspective-on-constructibility/), Chong, Chitat (ed.) et al., Infinity and truth. Based on talks given at the workshop, Singapore, July 25--29, 2011. Hackensack, NJ: World Scientific (ISBN 978-981-4571-03-6/hbk; 978-981-4571-05-0/ebook). Lecture Notes Series. Institute for Mathematical Sciences. National University of Singapore 25, 25-45 (2014). [DOI:10.1142/9789814571043_0002](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/9789814571043_0002),
> >      [ZBL1321.03061](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1321.03061).
> >
> > *Gitman, Victoria; Hamkins, Joel David*, [**A natural model of the multiverse axioms**](http://jdh.hamkins.org/naturalmodelofmultiverseaxioms/), Notre Dame J. Formal Logic 51, No. 4, 475-484 (2010). [DOI:10.1215/00294527-2010-030](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/00294527-2010-030), [ZBL1214.03035](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1214.03035).
> >
> > *Hamkins, Joel David; Yang, Ruizhi*, [**Satisfaction is not absolute**](http://jdh.hamkins.org/satisfaction-is-not-absolute/), to appear in the Review of Symbolic Logic.

But finally, to address your specific question. Of course, there
are specific finite numbers that will be finite with respect to any
alternative set-theoretic background. As Michael Greinecker points
out in the comments, the number 35253586543 has that value
regardless of your meta-mathematical position. So of course, there
are many proofs that are standard finite with respect to any of the
alternative foundations.

Meanwhile, I find it very interesting to consider the situation
where different foundational systems disagree on what is provable.
In very recent work of mine, for example, we are looking at the
theory of set-theoretic and arithmetic potentialism, where
different foundational systems disagree on what is true or
provable.

For example, recently with Hugh Woodin, I have proved that there is
a universal finite set $\{x\mid\varphi(x)\}$, a set that ZFC proves
is finite, and which is empty in any transitive model of set
theory, but if the set is $y$ in some countable model of set theory
$M$ and $z$ is any finite set in $M$ with $y\subset z$, then there
is a top-extension of $M$ to a model $N$ inside of which the set is
exactly $z$. The key to the proof is playing with the non-absolute
nature of truth between $M$ and its various top-extensions.

[image]

Comment: I've been away from MO for about a month, but came back to give an answer to this question.

Comment: Doesn't the Church-Turing Thesis give a strong argument for the absoluteness for what you call the pre-reflective account of the finite? What fundamentally new questions are raised by the application of non-absoluteness results in set theory to provability that don't already occur with much lower strength Gödelian phenomena?

Comment: @CameronZwarich:  " 'Every function can be computable!'... there is a universal algorithm, capable of computing any function...What I mean is that there a universal algorithm, a Turing machine program capable of computing any desired function, if only one should run the program in the right universe.  There is a Turing machine program $p$ with the property that for any function $f$:  $\mathbb N$ $\rightarrow$ $\mathbb N$ on the natural numbers, including non-computable functions, there is a model of arithmetic or set theory inside of which the function computed by $p$ agrees with $f$ on all

Comment: (cont.) standard finite input.  You have to run the program in a different universe in order that it will compute your desired function $f$."  (This from Prof. Hamkins' March 25, 2016 blogpost, "Every function can be computable!")  What this seems to mean (if I am understanding the concept correctly) is that (to use the 'multiverse' of universes of $PA$ as an example) if one fixes one of these universes satisfying $PA$ as the 'standard finite input', then, assuming Church's Thesis holds for all universes satisfying $PA$ (i.e. is '$PA$-absolute'?), there is a universe $M$ such that

Comment: (cont.) for every $f$: $M$ $\rightarrow$ $M$, $f$ is effectively computable in $M$.  So Church's Thesis does not seem to provide a strong argument for the "pre-reflective account of the finite" since within any given universe $M$ $\vDash$ $PA$, every element of $M$ is deemed 'finite'.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin The Church-Turing Thesis is not a mathematical statement, so if you are discussing it in the same breath as statements off the form "within any given universe $M \models PA$", you are already reflecting the mathematical notion of sets and satisfiability into the metatheory. (cont.)

Comment: The proof of the result you cite is basically just a careful analysis of the proof of the second incompleteness theorem, and all of the models involved satisfy $\neg \mathrm{Con}(PA)$. Do you interpret the second incompleteness theorem as implying that the consistency of PA is actually a nonabsolute notion, or do you interpret it as implying that the first-order theory PA, if consistent, is not capable of proving its own consistency?

Comment: Perhaps what I tried to say in the above comments would be better said as:  "Let universes $M$, $N$ $\vDash$ $PA$.  Then for every $f$:  $M$ $\rightarrow$ $M$, there exists a universe $N$ such that $M$ $\subset$ $N$ and $f$ is effectively recursive in $N$.

Comment: @CameronZwarich:  Does the Second Incompleteness Theorem imply the independence of $CON(PA)$, $\lnot$$CON(PA)$ from $PA$, that is, can one can consistently assume either $PA$ + $CON(PA)$ or $PA$ + $\lnot$$CON(PA)$?  Also, how does the Church-Turing thesis (a non-mathematical statement) give a strong argument for the absoluteness of what is called the pre-reflective account of the finite?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin It might be that $PA$ is consistent, but proves $\neg Con(PA)$, so $PA+Con(PA)$ is inconsistent. Godel's theorems only guarantee that if $PA$ is consistent, so is $PA+\neg Con(PA)$.

Comment: @CameronZwarich:  I interpret the Second Incompleteness theorem as implying that the first-order theory $PA$, if consistent, is not capable of proving its own consistency (though I hold that $PRA$ + $TI_{\epsilon_0}$ implies $CON(PA)$, so that both $PA$ and $PA$ + $\lnot$$CON(PA)$ have models).  Your move.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin My point was that these results supposedly establishing arithmetic non-absoluteness don't appear to have substantially different content than the incompleteness theorems, even if they are dressing it up in a more enticing semantic veneer. Therefore, if you don't interpret the second incompleteness theorem as establishing the actual non-absoluteness of the consistency of PA, then how can you interpret these other results as establishing arithmetic non-absoluteness?

Comment: This is great. I completely agree with you. For example, there are many ways to add using primes depending on one’s choice.

Comment: @CameronZwarich:  So would I be correct in saying that Godel's second incompleteness theorem (in your view) implies "arithmetic non-absoluteness" for universes satisfying $PA$ (and what would be the precise mathematical definition of 'arithmetic non-absoluteness', just for the record)?  Also, I am in sympathy with the view your latest comment states, just so you know.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin The second incompleteness theorem (when combined with the completeness theorem, which can be formalized in relatively weak theories) implies "arithmetic non-absoluteness" as a mathematical statement about models of first-order theories.

I think to most mathematicians (IMO of course, there is no survey) this does not introduce any new doubt about the absoluteness of our concept of finitary mathematics, where absoluteness in interpreted in an ordinary philosophical sense, not in a mathematical sense. (cont.)

Comment: For an ordinary set-theoretic realist, there is also no problem, because set theory proves the uniqueness of the structure of natural numbers. This absoluteness (and quite a bit more) is also true across forcing extensions of $V$ and inner models, assuming you permit yourself a metatheorem or your realism includes the second-order structure of $V$ necessary to express this absoluteness. 

However, if you accept a notion of set-theoretic realism that includes universes that are further from these examples, then you find you find yourself in a bit of a bind. (cont.)

Comment: You can use a construction not too far from the one that shows any function can be made computable to show that you can fix a structure and vary the truth of a statement across universes in your multiverse, and you can pick the minimum rank at which this phenomenon occurs. If the reason you believed in the (real-world) absoluteness of finitary mathematics in the first place was that ZF proves the uniqueness of the naturals, then you now have a problem. (cont.)

Comment: However, this just seems like a fancier second-order version of establishing $\mathrm{Con}(PA)$ by $\epsilon_0$-induction and then struggling to find a justification for $\epsilon_0$-induction.

Comment: This may be something of an off-topic comment, but one puzzlement I have (at the philosophical level) about these kinds of doubts about the natural numbers is that if we seriously entertain them, then I am no longer sure what "absolute" means. In other words, to state the challenge precisely, it seems that I have to say something like, "The word 'absolute' has a clear and definite meaning, and according to this clear and definite meaning, our concept of 'finite' is not absolute." But if I'm seriously unsure about the word 'finite' then won't I be similarly unsure about the word 'absolute'?

Comment: For example, Joel writes, "Of course, within the axiomatic system of ZFC or other systems, we have a clear definition of what it means to be finite." But if I am not sure what "finite" means then I will not be sure what ZFC is exactly. To specify the axiom schema, we have to invoke "and so on" at some point. If it is not completely clear what ZFC is, then it can't be used to provide a clear definition of what "finite" is.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins:  Regarding your Skolem example ("...there are models of set theory $M_1$, $M_2$, and $M_3$ with a set $A$ in common..."), do you have a cite for that, and what was Skolem's original example (i.e., did he know what an ultraproduct was...)?

Comment: (cont.) oops, I meant, "( ...did he know what an 'ultrapower by a ultrafilter on $\mathbb N$' was)?"  Sorry.

Comment: @TimothyChow:  What, exactly, is your "clear and definite meaning" of the term "absolute"?  For example (and you might not consider this a good example, considering the source), the Wikipedia entry "Absoluteness" states, "In mathematical logic, a formula is said to be absolute if it has the same truth value in each of some class of  structures (also called models)" (so that the term "absolute" is defined over a given class of models).  This seems to be (at least to my way of thinking--possibly bad....) an adequate intuitive definition of "absolute" for the set-theoretic multiverse where there

Comment: (cont.) is no fixed 'real world' $V$.  Given the  aforementioned definition of absolute in the Wikipedia entry, how does this definition (for example) contribute to any lack of clarity of what $ZFC$ is, given that the definition of the term "finite" may not be fixed in the set-theoretic multiverse?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin : If "finite" is hopelessly vague, then even "ZFC", let alone "models of ZFC", is hopelessly vague as well. Which ZFC are you talking about? All definitions of ZFC use "and so on" to describe axiom schemata, and if "and so on" is hopelessly vague then I am unclear what these axiom schemata are exactly. And if you're defining "absolute" in terms of hopelessly vague concepts such as "ZFC" and "model" then "absolute" is hopelessly vague as well.

Comment: @TimothyChow:  So you would say that since $ZFC$ has, say,  the following variants, e.g., $ZFC$ + $V$= $L$ and $ZFC$ + $\mathfrak M$[$G$] = $V$ (where $\mathfrak M$[$G$] is, say, a forcing extension in which $2^{\aleph_0}$=$\aleph_2$) then $ZFC$ is hopelessly vague?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin : No. You're not taking seriously enough the notion that "finite" is hopelessly vague. Look at the definition of ZFC. Look in particular at the axiom schema of comprehension. It's an axiom *schema* because it comprises one axiom for each formula. Tell me, Thomas, what is a formula? When you start trying to explain to me what a formula is, you will find yourself saying "and so on" at some point, just as when you try to explain what an integer is, you will say "and so on" at some point. If "and so on" is hopelessly vague, the so is "formula" and therefore so is ZFC.

Comment: @TimothyChow:  Would I be correcting in stating that it is some metatheory that determines the number of wffs that form subsets of a given set in the Separation axiom of $ZFC$ and that is that metatheory that determines the length of a formula in the metalanguage?  If so, would you counter that if that metatheory is "hopelessly vague", then one could not use that metatheory to 'fix' the length of a formula (since the length of a formula in that metatheory could be 'nonstandard finite') or the number of formulas represented by the Separation axiom?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin : Yes, that is pretty close to what I am saying. Mind you, I personally don't think that "finite" is hopelessly vague. But what I *am* saying is that *if* "finite" is hopelessly vague then so is "ZFC".

Comment: Timothy, yes, of course it is part of my view that different notions of the finite all give rise to different concepts of ZFC. The way I think about it is that it is wrong to think that there is only one meta-theoretic context. Rather, every object theory provides a meta-theoretic context for the theories it has, and those theories provide meta-theoretic contexts for further theories and so on. And also, it goes the other way: one makes stronger assumptions in the meta theory (such as consistency or whatever), and ultimately finds that one needs a meta-meta-theory and so on.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins:  Exactly how does a given "object theory provide a meta-theoretic context for the theories it has"?  For example (possibly a bad example), since it is known how to syntacticly represent nonstandard integers for $PA$, it is possible to Godel-number $PA^{'}$ ($PA$ with non-standard integers) in $PA$ so that $PA$ 'recognizes' the difference between standard and nonstandard integers, correct?  In any case (in practice) researchers studying $PA$ (for example)  always are able to distinguish between $PA$ and $PA^{'}$.  If $PA$ (say) is 'hopelessly vague', one might

Comment: (cont.) (philosophically) wonder how they manage to distinguish between $PA$ and $PA^{'}$?

Comment: When you prove the theorems of elementary model theory in ZFC, then you are essentially using ZFC as a meta-theory for the object theories you are considering. When you prove in ZFC (or much less) that every model of PA has an elementary top-extension, then you are proving something about the current version of the object theory PA. But those theories themselves can prove such theorems also, so we have many levels of meta-theory, and basically every foundational theory can serve as a meta-theory.

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins:  So then $PA$ can code $PA{'}$ (via Godel-numbering) so $PA$ can act as $PA^{'}$'s meta-theory and can distinguish between non-standard and standard numbers in $PA^{'}$?

Comment: (cont.)  (Actually it can't, for the simple reason that if it could, Tennenbaum's theorem would fail, i.e., there would exist countable recursive non-standard models of $PA$)  So perhaps a more suitable metatheory would be second-order $PA$, under the Henkin interpretation. Would second-order $PA$, under the Henkin interpretation, adequately capture the notion of the multiverse of first-order arithmetic universes satisfying $PA$?

Answer (score 16):

There is a subtle issue here but it is not where the OP thinks it is. Any explicitly written integer is obviously "standard" whereas each new integer arising in the ultrapower of $\mathbb N$ is obviously "nonstandard". The subtle issue is that in the particular $\mathbb N$ we are working with, there may be integers (certainly bigger than the explicitly written ones) that look nonstandard from the viewpoint of another set-theoretic universe.

But this does not change the fact that any concrete proof has "standard" length.  And since we are accepting ZFC axiomatics for each instance of a universe in Hamkins' multiverse, this has nothing to do with ultrafinitism.

In [this publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00425) (see also [here](http://msupress.org/journals/issue/?id=50-21D-61F)) we proved a theorem that each universe in the Hamkins-Gitman "toy model" actually turns out to be a model of a variant of Edward Nelson's *Internal Set Theory*. Translated into the terms of Robinson's framework, this means that the integers in each instance of a universe in the multiverse contain not only an initial cut including all explicitly specifiable integers, but also a wealth of integers that are infinite according to a "smaller" universe in the multiverse.

One should note that the idea of a "standard $\mathbb N$" being an illusion, as implied in these *question* and *answers*, was the main driving force behind [Petr Vopěnka's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petr_Vop%C4%9Bnka) approach to the foundations of mathematics, formulated as his [Alternative set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_set_theory) already in the 1970s, according to what I have read of Vopenka's work.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe explicitly written integers are "obviously standard" -- or more accurately, I don't think it's a meaningful proposition about the "real world". At least, not unless we do something trite like define "standard" to refer to explicitly written things rather than something resembling its formal usage.

Comment: @Hurkyl, the issue here was the length of an existing proof. That's a pretty clear sufficient condition for being *explicitly written*. Do you have an example of a published proof about which it is unclear whether its length is a standard integer?

Comment: @MikhailKatz:  A question.  Consider the proof of the totality of a function $f$($x$) recursive in some non-standard model $\mathfrak M$ of $PA$ whose totality was not provable in $<$ $\mathbb N$, $+$, $\cdot$ $>$, where $\mathbb N$ are just the 'naive integers' (refer back to you and your colleagues' paper regarding your view of Reeb's understanding of the 'naive integers').   The aforementioned proof in the extension $PA^{'}$ (containing the constants representing the 'nonstandard integers')  would certainly not be in $PA$ but could be explicitly written in $PA^{'}.  But Reeb contends that

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin, there is a problem in punctuation and latex formatting here.  Also the sequel is missing.  I can't really follow what you are getting at but it sounds interesting.

Comment: (cont.) (at least according to what is written in your paper), "The _naive integers_  are those integers that all members of humanity [in some universe where $PA$ holds whether standard or non-standard--my comment] share before they understand any advanced mathematics", so that the denizens of $\mathfrak M$ would consider their integers 'naive'.  Though it is clear that any recursive function provably total in $PA$ would be provably total in $PA^{'}$, the notions 'explicitly written in $PA$' and  'explicitly written in $PA^{'}$' do not coincide (my previous comment should read,

Comment: (cont.) "...in some non-standard model of $PA$ whose totality was not provable in $PA$ satisfying $<$ $\mathbb N$, $+$, $\cdot$ $>$,...").  Could such a situation actually exist?

Comment: To make a long story short, you seem to be asking the following.  Take a nonstandard integer $H$ in PA'.  It is explicitly written in PA' (namely, "H") but not explicitly written  in PA.  This shows that the notion of "explicitly written" is not well-defined.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: @MikhailKatz:  Somewhat.  According to (at least my understanding of) Prof. Hamkins' blogpost, "Every function can be computable!", there can exist proofs of the totality of functions recursive in some extension $PA^{'}$ in which non-standard integers exist that cannot be proven in $PA$.  Therefore, the notion of "explicitly written" is not well-defined.  In fact, since a nonstandard integer $H$ can be explicitly written in $PA^{'}$, this suggests that to the denizens of the universe in which $PA^{'}$ holds, $H$ is (to them) a "naive integer".

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin, I think you missed the point of my *answer*.  I agree that the notion of "explicitly written" is not well-defined, but there are some sufficient conditions for an integer to have been explicitly written.  Note that the collection of standard integers in Nelson's *Internal Set Theory* is ***not a set***.  This is the formal counterpart of a "soritic" property of being a "naive" integer or an "explicitly specifiable" integer. More on the sorites and the Robinson/Nelson framework can be found in [this publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00425).

Comment: @MikhailKatz:   Thanks.  I'll read further in you and your colleagues' paper.

Answer (score 11):

I think only Joel can answer this question, but I'd like to point out that there are some subtleties here that the commenters are missing. In Joel's multiverse conception, there is no "standard" $\mathbb{N}$, so the standard natural numbers in one model could turn out to be nonstandard in another model. This means that something that appears to be a proof in PA in one model would be revealed to have nonstandard length, and not be a proof, in some other model.

So: "Length 35253586543 is always length 35253586543"? I'm not even sure we know, from Joel's perspective, that 35253586543 is a standard natural number in every model. It would take a long long time to actually count that high. Surely in models with nonstandard $\mathbb{N}$ it *seems like* nonstandard numbers are standard, and you could count up to them and think that you had executed only a finite number of steps. So how could you know that numbers you think are standard are also seen as standard by everyone else? Maybe for small numbers you can just directly intuit this, but this gets pretty philosophical.

You could argue that this number is only 11 digits long, and maybe we could give a proof that all 11 digit long numbers have to be standard in every universe, such that the proof itself was sufficiently short that we could just directly "see" that it continues to be a proof in any model.  Maybe. That would at least require some serious argumentation.

"The actual proofs that we use have standard lengths" --- of course it would seem that way to us, but might our proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic turn out to have a nonstandard length in some other model? How could we know it wouldn't? You see these questions are a lot more subtle than they seem at first.

Edit: I guess I ought to clarify that I am NOT expressing my own view here. In my view, which is otherwise close to Joel's, there is a standard $\mathbb{N}$ and an absolute notion of arithmetical truth. However, there are no uncountable sets and "sets" like the real line are actually proper classes. So if ZFC is consistent then it has a range of countable models, but no canonical model.

I came to this view as a result of clarifying what I think is the essential difference between sets and proper classes (something philosophers of mathematics have struggled to explain). I have several papers on the arXiv which lay out my position; "Mathematical conceptualism" is probably the best place to start. The fullest account of my ideas about the set/proper class distinction is given in the last chapter of my book *Truth & Assertibility*.

Comment: Cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultrafinitism !

Comment: @MikeShulman: exactly. Though I would be surprised to hear Joel describe himself as an ultrafinitist ...

Comment: The individual models in the multiverse are supposed to be models of ZF, and it's fairly easy to (express and) prove in an extension by definitions of ZF that 35253586543 exists. And the length of the proof, including the relevant definitions, is (unlike 35253586543 itself) short enough that one could count up to it.  So 35253586543 should be "standard" in the sense of each model in the multiverse.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: but again, if your model has a nonstandard $\mathbb{N}$ then you could "count up to" nonstandard numbers and think they were standard.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I agree it's not exactly ultrafinitism, since there's no debate about whether 35253586543 *exists*; but if there is debate about whether it's "standard" then I think there is at least an analogy.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: The point is that you're observing the multiverse from the perspective of the particular universe in which you've "expressed and proved that 35253586543 exists". Every universe in your observable multiverse will have the integer 35253586543, but you can't say anything about universes outside of it.

Comment: I may have to wait for Joel's hopeful comments for this, but I'm a bit confused. I was under the impression that we can (metamathematically) take 'the' $\mathbb{N}$ as the intersection of all $\mathbb{N}$ over all theories; it's certainly true that no specific theory can talk about _this_ $\mathbb{N}$, but there is a theory (if not more) that has this minimal $\mathbb{N}$ as 'its' $\mathbb{N}$, and its theorems can't have nonstandard lengths in any other model. What part of this (if not several) am I confused about?

Comment: @NikWeaver Is there some paper in which you describe your views? I read your book on forcing and had the impression that you view the idea of standard natural numbers as harmless.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, one of the "points" of Hamkins' multiverse view is that the position you outlined does not hold there.  Namely, in every instance of a universe in the multiverse, the integers of that particular universe will contain nonstandard integers with respect to another universe.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker: thank you for the question. I've added a clarifying edit.

Comment: @NikWeaver, all naive integers including 35253586543 are present in each universe of the multiverse.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: on what basis do you say this? Is it just your opinion? (And what exactly is a "naive" integer?)

Comment: @Hurkyl My comment was written not from the viewpoint of some particular universe (in the multiverse), nor from the viewpoint of a ZF model or other mathematical structure, but from the "viewpoint" of the physical world in which we live. The expressing and proving that I have in mind is not about (standard or nonstandard) formulas or Gödel numbers thereof but about what could be written with actual physical pens on actual sheets of paper.

Comment: @NikWeaver, naive integers include anything you can write down in the time allotted to our civilisation using a computer as large as the universe and exploiting the fastest growing functions in our logical arsenal.  Writing down 35253586543 certainly takes less effort than that. For details you can see [my recent publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.00425), All in all this *question* would have been more appropriate at MSE.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: again, my main question for you is on what basis you make this confident statement of fact about Hamkins' multiverse conception.

Comment: Again, on the basis of what I wrote in the publication cited above.

Comment: @MikeShulman, there could not be any debate about whether 35253586543 is "standard" or any other explicitly specified number. The universes in Hamkins' multiverse are models of ZFC and therefore are unrelated to either finitism or ultrafinitism.

Comment: @MikhailKatz: I'm afraid you really don't understand the issues here. Joel does not believe in a standard $\mathbb{N}$. So you have to be careful about what it even means to be a model of ZFC. This matter is absolutely related to finitism and possibly even to ultrafinitism. The best source on this would be Joel. Presuming that you can give a categorical answer, as you have, is quite arrogant and unsupported.

Comment: "Not believing in a standard N" does not entail any of the philosophical anxieties you outlined, contrary to what you seem to assume. @NikWeaver

Comment: Is the statement "all naive integers are present in all universes of the multiverse" a metamathematical statement about natural numbers that are constructed as the result of physical processes, or is it a *mathematical* statement subject about an unbounded finitary process that is itself subject to non-absoluteness? Taking the latter view and importing the non-absoluteness of arithmetic statements about provability while also trying to establish absolute arithmetic statements about provability seems self-defeating and ultimately incoherent.

Comment: "In Joel's multiverse conception, there is no 'standard' N, so the standard natural numbers in one model could turn out to be nonstandard in another model. This means that something that appears to be a proof in PA in one model would be revealed to have nonstandard length, and not be a proof, in some other model": Weaver's first sentence is correct but his second sentence is not as Joel David's answer conclusively shows.

Comment: It should be noted that just because we can "see" a number doesn't make it standard. For example, in a non-standard universe, there could be a creature with a non-standard number of fingers. If we told them that their "10" doesn't exist, they would laugh at us.

Answer (score 4):

Since the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is a theorem of $PA$, it holds for both standard and nonstandard models of $PA$.  Since one can interpret $PA$ in both $ZFC$ and $GBC$ (e.g., for $ZFC$, it is interpretable in $ZFC$ as the fragment $ZFC$ $-$ *Infinity*--note that in $ZFC$ all definitions of "finite" are equivalent, while in $ZF$ there are an "infinitude of finitudes" but since $V_{\omega}$ $\vDash$ $ZF$ $-$ *Infinity* also satisfies $ZFC$ $-$ *Infinity*, all definitions of 'finite' for $V_{\omega}$ are still equivalent), one can see that $PA$ is interpretable in some background set theory so as long as one's model of $PA$ can be interpreted in a model of $ZFC$ (say), then the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic will hold.

[Addendum:  Though Andres is right, i.e., that interpretations are not theories, one can interpret one theory in another (see Richard Kaye's and Tin Lok Wong's paper, "On interpretations of arithmetic and set theory", for the interpretation of $PA$ in $ZF$ and $ZFC$).  I am using this interpretation in order to show that, given the right background set theory ($ZFC$), one still has that the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic will hold in models of $ZFC$ for its interpretation of $PA$, regardless of whether the model of $PA$ in question is 'standard' or 'nonstandard' (whatever those terms might mean in Hamkins' set-theoretic multiverse).]

Comment: No, an interpretation is not a theory.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo:  Correct.  Where did I say it was in my answer or my comments?  If you can show me I will correct (except in the comments--all of my comments were made more than five minutes ago).

Comment: I think this answer and the other comments are missing the point that in Hamkins' multiverse conception (as I understand it) there is no "standard" $\mathbb{N}$. That makes the question much more subtle and philosophical. I'd like to see Joel's response.

Comment: @NikWeaver:  In Hamkins' multiverse conception, can there be a "standard $\mathbb N$" relative to some given background set theory?  As I understand it, the relativity of $\mathbb N$ is due to a relativity of background set theory, as stated in the quote from Hamkins' preprint (I know it has been published a while back) I gave in my comments.

Comment: Thomas, read what you wrote.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo:  I did rewrite what was in the parentheses already.  Am I to presume that that editing did not correct the problem completely?  Since I have errands to run, I will correct these later--don't fault me for that, please.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin: I don't want to speak for Joel, but yes, it is also my understanding that the relativity of $\mathbb{N}$ is due to a relativity of background set theory. But that means that the concept "is a theorem of PA" varies depending on the background set theory.

Comment: One concern is that within any model, proofs that are of nonstandard length relative to some other model may seem to be of standard length. If you were to write out the proof of the fundamental theorem of arithmetic in PA, I'm sure it would be very long ... so could we be sure that it's not of nonstandard length in some model? I feel obliged to emphasize again that I don't speak for Joel and would be curious as to how he would answer the question.